# A question about GC

Tags: java

This is  a quesiton taken from a java exam,

How many objects are eligible for gabage collection at #1 ?

```
public class Main   {

Integer x = 32768;
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Main m = new Main();
    m = null;
    // #1
  } 
}
```

I thought it just collect Integer x, does GC even collect the Main object m?

Comment: The real question is how you could test this empirically. The answer to your question is 2, though: `x` and `m`. But I doubt the GC would fire before the program ends.

Comment: Additional question based on this OP: even though args hold a reference to the strings, could the JIT GC the args because there are no references? I'm wondering with happens-before ordering whether its legal. In practice the GC would never happen in such a small program. This is just a nerdcore question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does collect Main object. Since integer is neither a separate object by itself (it's a member of Main) not a pointer it won't be collected separately but only as a part of  Main.

Comment: Wouldn't the integer not be collected at all since it's a value object?

Comment: Integer (with an upper case) is an object

Comment: Err... This is Java. I kept thinking in C# here. You're right. It's a decorator for int.

Answer (score 3):

Two objects may be deleted by the garbage collector.

The object assigned to m is not reachable any more, nor is the Integer inside Main.

**Edit:** You can ask yourself: "Is it possible that I access the object in some way at this point?" If the answere is "No", the garbage collector may delete it.

Answer (score 2):

One bit of confusion you may be having is that the main method can be called without there even being a main object in existence.  That is because it is a static method.  Similarly, the "Integer x" only exists as a field in a main object. So when you create a new Main object  m you also create the integer m.x as part of m.  Then when you set m to null the object that was previously referred to by m is garbage and can be collected.

Now, when will it be collected is a totally different question.  There are really are no guarantees; however, since its use was so localized it will almost certainly be taken care of at the next minor collection/scavenge/pick-your-favorite'-terminology.

Answer (score 1):

It could. There is no reference to it anymore, so it is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `Main` is eligible for garbage collection and *normally* the Integer will also be eligible. But the Integer instance can also be cached by the `Integer` class if configured to do so (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030479/most-efficient-way-of-converting-string-to-integer-in-java/1030802#1030802)).

Normally only integers between -128 and 127 are cached when using [Integer#valueOf(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) (used for autoboxing) but the upper limit can be increased by setting the system property `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high`

Answer (score 0):

My observations using a recent OpenJDK have shown that only once a method exits do any references it orphaned actually get collected. I did not expect this at all, but it's what happened. Extracting those lines of code into another method, which would then return back to main(), *did* allow the instance to be collected.

I think this is a dumb question. (EDIT: I mean the exam question! Not insulting the submitter!) It's all in how you define "eligible".  In my case, I'd say once there were no references left, the instance was *eligible* to be collected, it's just that it never would actually *be* collected until sometime after the method returns.