# Fast way converting a byte array to corresponding Integer

Tags: java, string, integer, arrays

First, this sounds like the problem here:
[How to convert a byte array to its numeric value (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026761/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-its-numeric-value-java)

But the origin of my Byte-Array is a String, something like this:

```
byte[] foo = new byte[8];
foo = "12345678".getBytes();
```

Is there a faster way (yes its really about doing this quick) than
`Integer.parseInt(new String(foo))`?
The String contains only digits which represent a Integer.

Comment: Have you profiled your code and demonstrated that this is an actual (rather than perceived) bottleneck?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030479/most-efficient-way-of-converting-string-to-integer-in-java

Comment: Keeping the String reference, and applying Integer.parseInt to it, would save a couple of array copies.

Comment: It is unclear why you are using a byte array at all instead of `Integer.parseInt(originalString)`... By the way `new byte[8]` creates an array which is immediately discarded...

Comment: I am using a byte array, because the data is received via a RandomAccessFile using read().

Comment: I didn't profile the code, but extrapolated that it might save 2-3 seconds by multiplying the number of executions of this piece of code if the runtime could be reduced by about 50%. This is maybe a little bit too high as a expectation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = foo.length -1, m = 1; i >=0; i--, m *= 10) {
        res += (foo[i] & 0xF) * m; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
byte foo[] = "12345678".getBytes();
//Since it is an 'integer' essentially, it will contain ASCII values of decimal digits.
long num = 0;  //Store number here.
for(int i = foo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    num = num * 10 + (foo[i] - '0'); // or (foo[i] - 48) or (foo[i] & 0xf)
}
```

`num` stores the required number.

**Precaution**: Make sure you use decimal number only.

---

**EDIT:**

#### The Mechanism

On calling `getBytes()` of the `String` `"12345678"`, the `byte[]` returned is as follows:

[image]

The values we see are the **ASCII** or **Unicode** values for the eqivalent characters.
There are several ways to extract their equivalent character as `int`s:

1. Since the arrangement of the digit `chars`, i.e. '0', '1', '2', etc. are done in the desired order - ascending and sequentially, we can extract the characters by subtrcting the **ASCII** value of `'0'` i.e. 48.
2. @Evgeniy Dorofeev correctly pointed out the method of *masking*:

> '0' => 48 => 11 0000

We notice that if we extract the last 4 bits, we get the required `int`.
To do this, we need to extract them in the following way.
Let us take `foo[1]`, i.e. 50

```
  50      & 0xf  (original)
= 50      & 15   (in Decimal)
= 11 0010 & 1111 (in Binary)
= 0010           (result)
= 2              (Decimal)
```

Hence, the required digit is obtained. It in necessary to `add` it to `num` int the correct way (which I expect of every programmer to have some knowledge about).