# Best way to convert String to Integer or int

Tags: java

This might asked too many times before but...

```
String str = "74.0";
```

let say I have `"74.05"` and I only need the `74`. Below are some of my ways..

```
Integer.parseInt(str); //would result to java.lang.NumberFormatException
(int) Double.parseDouble(str); //working
new BigDecimal(str).intValue(); //I like this
```

I want this string(`str`) converted to `int` or `Integer`, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: what if you have 74.90, do you still want 74?

Comment: yes only the 74. I think rounding would will lead to another question

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030479/most-efficient-way-of-converting-string-to-integer-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: [Yes another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau the second link answer will result to `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the string has `.`

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.NumberFormatException` is due to the fact that you are trying to convert a `double` literal to a an `int` type.

There is not a *best way* but the usage of

```
Double.parseDouble("74.05");
```

instead of

```
Double.valueOf("74.05");
```

depends on your need of a `double` primitive type or a `Double` object type.

If you need an integer type, you can round the double value like this:

```
Math.round(Double.parseDouble("74.05"));
```

or simply cast the `double` to obtain the integral part only

```
(int)Double.parseDouble("74.05")
```

The `new BigDecimal(str).intValue();` is surely the **worst choiche** because can lead to unespected results as stated in the *Oracle* documentation (see the bold):

> `public int intValue()`
>
> Converts this BigDecimal to an int. This conversion is analogous to the narrowing primitive conversion from double to short as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: any fractional part of this BigDecimal will be discarded, and if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. **Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude and precision of this BigDecimal value as well as return a result with the opposite sign**.

---

Unrelated to the question, there is a sometime *faster* way when you need to instantiate an `Integer` from an `int` value.
From the `java.lang.Integer` `class` documentation:

> `public static Integer valueOf(int i)`
>
> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

Comment: Any value that is too big to fit into a `int` will not be good even if you don't use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: **"if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned"** I think same thing happens when you cast Double to int

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau and @yesterdaysfoe you both are right but my point was that `Integer.parseInt()` raises an exception while `new BigDecimal(str).intValue()` does not. Anyway I missed the point that `Double.parseDouble(str)` does not raise an exception too returning `+/-Infinity`

Answer (score 1):

`int x = (int) Double.parseDouble(s);`

ran in 3 nano seconds,

`int y = new BigDecimal(s).intValue();`

ran in 8 nano seconds

Answer (score 0):

a really somewhat unorthodox solution would be:

```
Integer.parseInt(str.split("\\.")[0]);
```

but it works with Strings like "74.09" and Strings like "74" and so on

Comment: this may work but I think this will process two different strings. Since, String is immutable it will consume more memory.

Answer (score 0):

How about

Integer myNum = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("."));

since the OP explicitly wanted NO rounding