# Query related to Numbers Class in Java

Tags: java

Could someone please tell me how do we calculate Integer.parseInt("444", 16) and 
and Integer.valueOf("444", 16)
where 16 is the radix and 444 which is String would be converted to an Integer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between parseInt and valueOf in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508665/difference-between-parseint-and-valueof-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for how the parsing works? Peek into the source of Integer - `valueOf()` invokes `parseInt()`