# Which one is faster? Integer.valueOf(String string) or Integer.parseInt(String string)?

Tags: java, android

I want to know which method is faster?

`Integer.valueOf(String string)` or `Integer.parseInt(String string)`?

Is there any Performance or Memory difference between the two approaches?

I have seen [Difference between parseInt and valueOf in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508665/difference-between-parseint-and-valueof-in-java) but this does not explains difference in terms of performance.

Comment: See [this][1].
Please search google and SO before asking questions.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508665/difference-between-parseint-and-valueof-in-java

Comment: you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355024/integer-valueof-vs-integer-parseint

Comment: My question is about performance. not about difference between these to methods.

Comment: you should reopen the question. because it is about performance that is not discussed in mentioned answers.

Comment: `Integer.valueOf("1")` is functionally equivalent to `Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt("1"))`; alternatively `Integer.parseInt("2")` is equivalent to `Integer.valueOf("2").intValue()`. Because they return different types, there is no situation where one is a direct replacement, so you need to ask about the performance of whichever one gives you the type you actually require, or better how to get the performance you require for a larger chunk of your code.

Comment: @Linaina If you did solve this problem, Accept any of the answers below

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would not look at performance. The API says that `Integer.valueOf(String)` is interpreted the same as if it has been passed to `Integer.parseInt(String)`, except it is wrapped into an `Integer`. I would look at what you need: an `Integer` or an `int`.

`Integer.valueOf` returns an `Integer`.

`Integer.parseInt` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 7):

`Integer.valueOf()` uses `Integer.parseInt()` internally and `valueOf` returns `Integer` Object whereas `parseInt()` returns `int`.
So `parseInt()` is faster.

Answer (score 2):

`valueOf(String)` returns a `new Integer()` object whereas `parseInt(String)` returns a primitive `int`.

Comment: This can be easily be shown to be false by running `System.out.println(Integer.valueOf ( "1" ) == Integer.valueOf ( "1" ));`

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.valueOf(String string)` returns a newly created wrapped **object**.

`Integer i = Integer.valueOf("5");`

`Integer.parseInt(String string)` returns the named **primitive**.

`int i = Integer.parseInt("5");`

Comment: So if I invoke Integer.valueOf("2") from MyClass, then it returns a new instance of MyClass, because that is the type which invoked the method?

Comment: why are so much concern, which one faster, even they are not same. I mean, their return type are different.

Comment: @PeteKirkham please refer kathy sierra book (SCJP Guide).And, i believe, It doesn't mean that, it means, it return Integer class object.

Comment: @PeteKirkham, now is this ok ?? or still require more improvement ??

Comment: @PeteKirkham, either tell me what's wrong in my answer or undo your downvote.

Comment: As I pointed out, the type returned is not anything to do with the type which invoked the method. Whatever invokes Integer.valueOf, it always returns an Integer.