# Conversions of strings to Integer and to int

Tags: java, string, integer

Given that String `s` has been declared, the following 5 lines of code produce the same result:

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(s);
int y = Integer.parseInt(s);
int j = Integer.valueOf(s).intValue();
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(s);
Integer k = Integer.valueOf(s).intValue();
```

Are there circumstances where each one would be the preferred code?  It appears that `int` and `Integer` are interchangeable and that `.intValue()` is not needed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933287/which-one-is-faster-integer-valueofstring-string-or-integer-parseintstring-s

Comment: how are you planning to use the var after assignment? You might not need an Integer at all

Comment: `Integer z = Integer.parseInt(s);` should work too.

Answer (score 7):

If you require an `int`, use `parseInt()`, if you require an `Integer` use `valueOf()`. Although they're (sort of) interchangeable now, it still makes more sense to use the one that directly returns the data type that you require. (Historically, they weren't interchangeable at all, this was introduced with auto-boxing and unboxing in Java 5.)

The `intValue()` method you're using is just converting the `Integer` class type to the `int` primitive, so using that and `valueOf()` is the worst possible combination, you never want to use that. (Nothing bad will happen, it's just longer to read, performs slightly worse and is generally more superfluous.)

If you don't care or don't know, then I'd use `parseInt()`. Especially as a beginner, it's more common that you want the primitive type rather than the class type.

Comment: The text I'm using introduced parseInt() and valueOf methods together and intruduces wrapper types later in the text. Thanks. – Nick

Answer (score 3):

`int` and `Integer` are made to look interchangeable by the magic of auto-boxing and auto-unboxing: In many cases where you need one but have the other, the compiler automagically inserts the necessary code to convert them.

This is useful, but if you know about it, you can avoid it in many places which results in slightly faster code (because there's less conversion to do).

- [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) returns an `int`, so you should use it if you need an `int`
- [`Integer.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) returns an `Integer`, so you should use it if you need an `Integer`
- `Integer.valueOf().intValue()` *first* creates an `Integer` and *then* extracts the `int` value from it. There's no good reason to use this instead of a simple `Integer.parseInt()`.

The decision between `int` and `Integer` is easy to do as well:

- *generally* you'd want to use the primitive type (`int`), if possible
- if you need an `Object` (for example, if you want to put your number in a `Collection`), then you need to use the wrapper type (`Integer`), as the primitive type can't be used here.

Comment: SUPER explanation!  I haven't got to Collections and wrapper types yet.  The text I'm using introduced parseInt() and valueOf methods together and intruduces wrapper types later in the text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

int and Integer are not interchangeable.Because of Autoboxing feature fron java 5 onwards,  int to Integer conversion is taken care by jvm itself.But we should not use Integer class unnecessarily.Primitive data types are always faster.Wrapper classes should be used only required.

Comment: Actually autoboxing/unboxing is a compiler thing. The JVM itself doesn't know about it.