# How to convert from string to integer? Keep getting NumberFormatException using valueOf();

Tags: java, string, integer, numberformatexception

I'm trying to convert a string to an Integer (not primitive int) before I store it in a `Stack<Integer>`, but I keep getting a `NumberFormatException` if I use this syntax:

```
String element = "5 ";
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(element));
```

Could someone explain how to use `valueOf();` correctly?

edit: I've tried parseInt(); which gives the same exception, and I want it in an Integer, not int, anyway.

Comment: There's a space after your digit. Use `element.trim()` to remove it before passing it to `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Integer.valueOf` will balk on any non-numeric characters. Either remove the trailing space manually or call `String#trim()`:

```
String element = "5 ";
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(element.trim()));
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't like the space.  Trim the input.  Change

```
String element = "5 ";
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(element));
```

to

```
String element = "5 ";
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(element.trim()));
```

It doesn't matter if you use `valueOf` or `parseInt`; neither seems to like the trailing space.

Comment: Because `valueOf` uses `parseInt` under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Integer.parseInt()` instead, which should be `Integer.parseInt(element)`.

Seems the space after 5 is causing that. `Integer.valueOf(element)` should still work without the space.

Cheers.

Comment: Same exception as before with that.

Comment: You should use whichever of `valueOf` or `parseInt` makes sense. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7355056/7708