# distinguishing cases to use interger.parseInt and string casting methods

Tags: java, methods, casting

I am developing a Java program and I'm meeting cases where I get undecided whether to use the casting a string to integer method, or to use the `integer.parseInt` method. Is there any clear benefit for either of the two methods?

With 'casting to string method', I mean:

```
String.valueOf(integer);
```

Comment: Please clarify _to cast a string to integer method_.

Comment: (Don't add code to comments. Edit your question.) Did you try running that code?

Comment: `String.valueOf(integer)` is not casting. It is calling a method. Looking at the source code for it would be enlightening.

Comment: @ David,i happen to have been examined in a java-based interview with this question which proved difficult:Explain the difference between casting a string to an integer and using the Integer.parseInt.please clarify.
method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer.valueOf() vs. Integer.parseInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355024/integer-valueof-vs-integer-parseint)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to cast from a String to an int, so using Integer.parseInt seems like the best option here.

Looking at your edits about using valueOf, perhaps this link may help: [Integer.valueOf() vs. Integer.parseInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355024/integer-valueof-vs-integer-parseint)

Comment: This is a link-only answer and should really be left as a comment instead.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I'm quite new here so I didn't know. :)