# How can I convert the string [1,2,3,4,5] into an integer array?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

```
def array = [1,2,3,4,5]
def b = int[array.length]
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    b[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i])
}
```

Should I use `Integer.parseInt`, Integer.valueOf or other methods?

Should I include a for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer.valueOf() vs. Integer.parseInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355024/integer-valueof-vs-integer-parseint)

Comment: I'm not sure how the code you posted has anything to do with the title.

Comment: I obtain a variable which result is the string 1,2,3,4,5 but I need it to be an integer array

Comment: "I obtain a variable which result is the string 1,2,3,4,5 but I need it to be an integer array" - That is very different than the code sample you included in the question.

Comment: It feels like at least once a day, someone asks about how to parse "accidental toString" back into some datastructure. While your question might be totally valid, be double sure, that you don't have to bother with this just because someone did the .toString() or a cast or could not decide for a proper format to transport structured data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
def array = [1,2,3,4,5]
def b = int[array.length]
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    b[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i])
}
```

You could do this:

```
def array = [1,2,3,4,5]
def b = new int[array.size()]
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    b[i] = i
}
```

You could also do this:

```
def array = [1,2,3,4,5]
def b = array.toArray(Integer[])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 9+, you can [stream the matches from a regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--):

```java
Pattern.compile("\\d+")
    .matcher(s)
    .results()
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! This also worked!

Answer (score 0):

Another option: take all numbers from the string as list and then cast them

```
"1, 2, 3".findAll(/\d+/) as Integer[]
```