# How to read in and split a string of numbers separated by whitespace and forward slash

Tags: java, string, split

Sample input: 1/2 3/4 5/6 7/8 9/10

What I expect it to do: first split the string based on whitespace, so you end up with a string array of {1/2 , 3/4 , 5/6 , 6/8 , 9/10}, and then split that into an array of integers intA{1,2}, intB{3,4}, intC{5,6}, intD{7,8}, intE{9,10} so that I can finally pass them into a fraction object with a numerator and denominator.

Here is what I currently have:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    str = keyboard.nextLine();
    String[] splitStr = str.split(" ");

    Fraction[] input = new Fraction[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++)
    {
        String[] fract = splitStr[i].split("/");
        int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
        int den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
        double fraction = (double)num / den;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(input[i]);
    }
}
```

When I input the above string, I get null values back. If I enter any values without a forward slash, like so: `1/2 3/4 5/6 7 8 9/10` instead of reading the 7 and 8 as 7/1 and 8/1 the program runs into a NullPointerException error. There has got to be an easier way to do this, isn't there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get null values back

That is because you don't add any values to the `input`, you only initalize  it which will fill it with `null` values.

I'm not sure how you create `Fraction` objects but you need to create this kind of objects and add them to the array. Here is an example:

```
Fraction[] input = new Fraction[10];

for(int i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    String[] fract = splitStr[i].split("/");
    int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
    int den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
    input[i] = new Fraction(num, den);
}
```

If you want to set the `denominator` to `1` when the input contains single numbers, you can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    String[] fract = splitStr[i].split("/");
    int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
    int den = 1;
    if(fract.length == 2){
        den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
    }
    input[i] = new Fraction(num, den);
}
```

Also, it is safer to set the `input` array's length to be equal to the `splitStr` array's length.

```
Fraction[] input = new Fraction[splitStr.length];
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually managed to get the fractions into the array before seeing your answer, but the point about setting the `input` array length to be equal to `splitStr` was helpful, as was how to handle a whole number being entered. I think that is about as compact as you can get the code in Java. I was feeling lost in a sea of indexes.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what the practical difference between `Integer.parseInt()` and `valueOf()` is?

Comment: @AxelFinkel You can find details about that [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508665/difference-between-parseint-and-valueof-in-java). Usually, `List`s are prefered instead of arrays, the size of a list can be changed and it is easier to iterate them.

Answer (score 0):

For numbers without den ( 7 8 ) you need to check the length of fract:

```
String[] fract = splitStr[i].split("/");
int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
int den = 1
if(fract.length > 2)
        den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++)
{  
    // if statement works for 7 or 8
    if(splitStr[i].length() == 1){
       // do something

    } else if(splitStr[i].length() == 3){
       String[] fract = splitStr[i].split("/");
       int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
       int den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
       double fraction = (double)num / den;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like `\s(\d+\/\d+)+` to check if the string is composed of fractions and manage the situation accordingly.