# String "Switch Case" simple code

Tags: java

I just started learning myself Java.  Thought of writing a "Switch case" program like to get a input string from user and thought of displaying the day.  Even though it did not show any errors in my Eclipse IDC but my below program is not running.

Could someone tell me what is the error in my below program?

```
package MyExercies;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class sampleSwitchCase 

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Day = S.nextLine();
        int weekday = Integer.valueOf(Day);
        S.close();      
        switch(weekday)
        {
        case 1:     
            System.out.println ("The given day is Week begining day - Monday");
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            System.out.println ("The given day is Mid of Weekday");
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println ("The given day is Weekend - Friday");
            break;

        case 6:
        case 7:
            System.out.println ("The given day is End of the Week");
            break;

        }

    }   

}
```

Comment: You should say more about what “not running” means.

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Package names and variable names (as well as method names) should start with a lower case character. Class names with upper case characters. So `myExercise`, `SampleSwitchCase`, `s` and `day`.

Comment: Posted code works here. Inefficient and non-standard variable names. But it works.

Comment: This code is working

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't run and not just wait for your input? Try printing something before your scanner so that you see if it ever starts.

Comment: Please don't close a something tied to the resource `System.in`. The stream was not opened by you but by the JVM. The one that opens a resource is responsible for closing it, so the JVM will close `System.in`.

Comment: Everything is good and working with your Code!

Comment: You need to enter a numerical value from 1 to 7 within the **Console Window** for you to get the results you expect. Anything other than a number will generate a **NumberFormatException** since the **Integer.valueOf()** method can only accept string representations of either signed or unsigned numerical characters. In this case it may be better to use **Integer.parseInt()** and [here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508665/difference-between-parseint-and-valueof-in-java). The difference is `valueOf()` returns an `Integer`, and `parseInt()` returns an `int` (a primitive type).

Answer (score -1):

Everything is good and working with your Code!

Just add :

```
 default :
            System.out.println("Write something default  here");
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  Added default section but still it is running without returning any result like showing red icon/button in my "Eclipse IDC".

Answer (score -1):

add `default`  case in your code and try  like this :

```
switch(weekday)
        {
        case 1:     
            System.out.println ("The given day is Week begining day - Monday");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("default case");
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  Added default section but still it is running without returning any result like showing red icon/button in my "Eclipse IDC".

Answer (score -2):

Add a `default` case in your `switch` block. For example:

```
switch(exp) {
   case 1:
      break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

Comment: **default:** is not a requirement but an option. How will this solve the OP's situation?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  Added default section but still it is running without returning any result like showing red icon/button in my "Eclipse IDC".