# How to multiply all the digits of an int without converting them to string and then using the charAt function with a for loop?

Tags: java

basically, I want to try out the persistence bugger and I'm new to java coding so I'm still using NetBeans GUI to code (I know) but I need help to make it work. Have attached my efforts below. The GUI is just a textField that takes input and a button with the given code. If someone could help that would be great.  Thanks in advance.

The error I kept getting was: 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
(4 is the length of the number I entered. It kept varying accordingly)

[The GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIlUL.png)

```
long num1=Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText());
String num2=jTextField1.getText();
char s1;
int pers=1,temp;
for(int i=1;i<=num2.length();i++)
{
  s1=num2.charAt(i);
  temp=Character.getNumericValue(s1);
  pers*=temp;
  if(pers==0)
   {
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
   }
}


String num2=jTextField1.getText();
String test=num2;
char s1;
int pers=num2.length(),temp=1,i,n=0;
  do
  {
      for(i=0;i<pers;i++)
   {
    s1=test.charAt(i);
    temp=temp*(Character.getNumericValue(s1));
   }
    test=Integer.toString(temp);
    temp=1;
  } while(test.length()>1);
  System.out.println(n);

  Final working code:
  long r1=Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText());
  String s=jTextField1.getText(),s1="";
  long r=1;
  int i=0;
  char[] gfg=s.toCharArray();
  do
   {
    for (char ch : gfg) 
     {
      r *= Character.digit(ch, 10);
     }
      s1=Long.toString(r);
      gfg=s1.toCharArray();
      System.out.println(r);
      r=1;
   }while(s1.length()!=1);
```

Comment: Strings in Java go from 0 to length-1, not 1 to length.

Comment: I know everyone is saying that its 0 to < length but I entered 1 to <= length doesn't that imply that the loop repeats the equal amount of times as 0 to <length?

Comment: Computers count from 0. So calling `String.charAt(0)` is calling the first character of the String. Calling `array[0]` is calling the first index of the array. Your `IndexOutOfBoundsException` can easily be stopped by changing `for(int i=1; i<=num2.length(); i++){` to `for(int i=0; i<num2.length(); i++){`

Comment: Ah 'kay I remember that now will make changes accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to fix your given error is simple.

Computers count from 0. So calling `String.charAt(0)` is calling the first character of the String. Calling `array[0]` is calling the first index of the array. Calling **`String.charAt(1)`** or **`array[1]`** is calling the **second** element.

Your IndexOutOfBoundsException can easily be stopped by changing

`for(int i=1; i<=num2.length(); i++){` to `for(int i=0; i<num2.length(); i++){`

---

The reason why your code produces an error is:

When the loop starts, your code skips the first character.

In the last iteration of the for-loop where `i == num2.length()` causes the problem because you attempt to call the non-existant **N+1**th character of a string while the length is only **N**.

---

The reason why your edited code causes an error is because in the line `test=Integer.toString(temp);`, you make `test` become a smaller number. (Probably)

Let's say `num2` was 989. `Test = num2` and `pers = num2.length(), which is 3` This is important.

After this line `test=Integer.toString(temp);`, test becomes `9`. (As a String)

Remember how `test` is only a single `length 1` digit? Well, in the next iteration of the do while loop, inside of the for loop, `i` to `pers` is `0` to `3.` However, again, `test` is only a single digit where it's length is 1.

In your for loop try adding `System.out.println(test.charAt(i))`.

---

The most important part of code is the logic behind it. If you lose the code you typed but kept a sheet of planning on how to make it, then you can fabricate the code again. If you forget the logic behind the code, and your teacher asks you to explain it, you're going to start from scratch.

The logic behind your code (as described in the title) to multiply each digit in a number is like this.

Input `String`

```
Make COUNT integer, equal to 1
Loop: (Use String like char[] array)
    Call String.charAt(int)
    Parse String.charAt(int)
    COUNT (<<placeholder name) *= parsed integer (valueOf returns the Integer wrapper class, you used int instead)
End loop
Print result
```

[Difference between parseInt and valueOf in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508665/difference-between-parseint-and-valueof-in-java)

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Analyze my "fix" to your code.

Comment: So basically I took advice from both @FallingCoder and Elliott and I made two separate buttons containing each of your codes and no offense Elliott but yours couldn't handle large numbers while the 0 to <length worked :P Thanks to both of you. Also, as a new user, I was surprised at how fast the answers came in. Keep it up guys. :)

Comment: While it may seem like it'll take at least an hour to get views on your question, the reality is that it'll only take about 5 seconds or so.

Comment: Guys I know I shouldn't trouble you all after all that but can you help me find the mistake in this...I'm getting the same error as before.

Comment: String num2=jTextField1.getText();
String test=num2;
char s1;
int pers=num2.length(),temp=1,i,n=0;
  do
  {
      for(i=0;i<pers;i++)
   {
    s1=test.charAt(i);
    temp=temp*(Character.getNumericValue(s1));
   }
    test=Integer.toString(temp);
    temp=1;
  } while(test.length()>1);
  System.out.println(n);

Comment: wait I'll put it in the question

Comment: @FallingCoder I added the new snippet at the bottom of the question. Please help.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @FallingCoder the same error as before. The persistence works for numbers that contain zero and gives the output as 1 but for any other number for example 235, instead of giving 2, it just gives this error again Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2

Comment: In your code, `test.length()` never changes. I didn't manage to find the source of the error though.

Comment: @FallingCoder but test gets changed to temp right so that changes the length i guess

Comment: I get it now. I don't see why you changed `test` to effectively be a single character. The source of the problem lies in the fact that `pers` does not change **with** `test`. As a result, when you call `test.charAt(Anything above 0)` it will create an IndexOutOfBounds exception. Why? Because `test` changed to a single character, and you call `test.charAt(pers)` where `pers` is likely above 0. Because `test.charAt(0)` is the first character, and `test.charAt(>0)` calls non-existent characters, it causes this error. (This line changes it: `test=Integer.toString(temp);`)

Comment: @FallingCoder wait, why should pers keep changing? pers is just used in the for loop right and not anywhere else. Also, in my code its test.charAt(i) and if I'm correct, i goes from 0 to length as you mentioned earlier. So, I don't see where the outofbounds error creeps in...

Comment: Let's say that `num2` is "12". `pers` would then be 2. You enter the do-while loop and then the for loop. `s1 = temp.charAt(i)`. It doesn't throw an error, because `i=0` and `test` is "12". `s1 = '1'`. `temp *= 1`. Next iteration of the for-loop: `temp *= 2`. No errors yet. After the for-loop, you call **`test=Integer.toString(temp);` which changes test to a single character.** So `test` would be `1`. (String) Because `pers` was equal to `2`, and `test.length()` would be `1`, calling `s1=test.charAt(i);` would cause an error. More specifically, an *`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.*

Comment: Think. I've given you an entire explanation. If you can't do this then I'm going to believe you copied half of this off the internet.

Comment: I didn't but I know it may sound like it though. Although your explanation makes sense, I really don't understand the part where you explain why the second iteration causes a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error. Also, I cannot express it enough but I'm really thankful to you for bearing with me. I'm still a dummy so thanks. :)

Comment: I've completely rewritten my explanation and put it in my answer. I will not re-write it again, and I don't want to edit it either.

Comment: @FallingCoder Im gonna try putting in i<test.length() instead of pers and see if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: look at the final working code I have added it in the question

Comment: Why do you need a do-while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your input is already a `String`, convert it to a `char[]` and use a `for-each` loop. Like,

```
int r = 1;
for (char ch : jTextField1.getText().toCharArray()) {
    r *= Character.digit(ch, 10);
}
```

Alternatively, valid indices are `0` (inclusive) to `length` (exclusive). So your `for` loop should look like

```
int i=1;i<=num2.length();i++
```

should be

```
int i=0; i < num2.length(); i++
```

Based on your comment below that you need to do it twice, I would extract the logic to a method and call it twice. Like,

```
private static int multiplyDigits(int r) {
    int t = 1;
    while (r > 0) {
        t *= r % 10;
        r /= 10;
    }
    return t;
}
```

And then

```
String str = "4544";
System.out.println(multiplyDigits(multiplyDigits(Integer.parseInt(str))));
```

Comment: can you explain in detail what the initial code lines are for? I entered them into the GUI and entered 4544 in jTextField1 and r was 320. I don't understand...

Comment: But 4*5*4*4 is 320. What did you expect?

Comment: I think he wanted an explanation..? I don't know personally.

Comment: But then I need the number of times it takes for the multiplication to reach 0. So, do I put that in a loop again and have another variable to count the number of times?

Comment: @FallingCoder yeah an explanation would have been good but I got it anyway. Thanks. Although the other question I asked still bugs me. Do i need to put that for loop nested inside another one?

Comment: @AmaanShaikh No. Why would you need a nested loop?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nested loop because, 4*5*4*4 gives me 320 but that isnt what i need ....I need the output as 2 because 4*5*4*4 = 320 then 3*2*0 = 0 so 2 steps

Comment: @ElliottFrisch your edited method works but only if I know the number of times the function has to repeat.

Comment: @AmaanShaikh Next time you ask a question, **please** include ***all* relevant** details **in** the question.

Comment: I'm sorry. Honestly I can't find the error in the latest code and I don't exactly know why. Your method works but isnt enough :\

Comment: @ElliottFrisch your code worked...though i had to tweak it a lot....I'll add it in the question so you can look at the masterpiece you have helped to to create. Although, I am certainly not ignoring FallingCoder's help and suggestions. Thanks a lot to both of you. Cheers